# How do I create an OpenGL ES 2 context in a native activity?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, egl

For the life of me, I cannot find any good pure Android NDK examples for OpenGL ES 2. The one included `native-activity` sample project builds an ES 1 context. Are there any sample programs demonstrating the creation of an ES 2 context in pure C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating an OpenGL ES 2 context should be about the same than creating an OpenGL ES 1. Based on the "native-activity" sample from the NDK, you just need to add this to the attribute list passed to `eglChooseConfig`:

```
const EGLint attribs[] =
{
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    ...
    EGL_NONE
};
```

This should ensure your config is ES2-compatible.

Then pass this attribute list to `eglCreateContext`:

```
EGLint AttribList[] = 
{
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
    EGL_NONE
};
```

with a call like this:

```
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, AttribList);
```

Comment: Ironically, I found the solution in a tutorial for OpenGL ES 2 on Raspberry Pi. Thanks for the clear answer, though. This is indeed the answer.